# orderBy date fllter angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angularjs-orderby

Hi I'm beginner in Angular. I am facing a problem with using date comparison with `orderBy` filter. The problem is that filter does not consider month and year. Here are the code snippets (also available on **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4eLaavu0/1/)**)

**SCRIPT**

```
var list = [
  {
    name: 'Jon',
    joining_date:'23/10/2015', 
    age: 23
  }, {
    name:'Viki', 
    joining_date:'24/01/2015',
    age: 20
  }, {
    name: 'Abc',
    joining_date:'25/10/2015',
    age: 43
  }, {
    name: 'XYZ', 
    joining_date:'28/10/2015',
    age: 21
  }
];

var empApp = angular.module('emp-list', []);
empApp.controller('emp-table',function($scope){
    $scope.data = list;
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="emp-list">
  <div class="search-box">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchKeyword"></input>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="emp-table">
    <table width="100%">
      <tr>
        <th width="33%">Name</th>
        <th width="33%">Joining Date</th>
        <th width="33%">Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="lists in data | filter: searchKeyword | orderBy : 'joining_date'">
         <td>{{lists.name}}</td>
         <td>{{lists.joining_date}}</td>
         <td>{{lists.age}}</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**RESULT**

```
Name    Joining Date    Age
Jon      23/10/2015     23
Viki     24/01/2015     20
Abc      25/10/2015     43
XYZ      28/10/2015     21
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `joining_date` is a string instead of `Date` object. As the result `orderBy` compares them as strings. Here is your fixed example: https://jsfiddle.net/bocn0vrb/1/.

You can also use a custom function for comparing those strings with some casting. Take a look at documentation page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy.

Comment: @Kamal No problem. Mark the post as the answer if everything is clear :)

Answer (score 0):

I got one more solution without changing my json data.. please check my code below.

I just created a following function which will convert dates from string to date format

```
$scope.dateFormate = function(joinDate){
        return new Date(joinDate)
    }
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var list = [{
                        name: 'Jon',
                        joining_date:'2015-10-23', 
                        age: 23
                    },
                    {
                        name:'Viki', 
                        joining_date:'2015-01-24',
                        age: 20
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Abc',
                        joining_date:'2015-10-25',
                        age: 43
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'XYZ', 
                        joining_date:'2015-10-21',
                        age: 21
                }];


var empApp = angular.module('emp-list', []);
empApp.controller('emp-table',function($scope){
    $scope.data = list;

    $scope.dateFormate = function(joinDate){
        return new Date(joinDate)
    }
})
```